# JAXB Large byte[] field

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a problem where I have to process an XML that has a large binary content.

Usually I would define the model class like this:

```
@XmlType
public class DataContainer {
  byte[] content;

  // getters/setters
}
```

Now with content in the magnitude of ~1GB un-/marshalling becomes a major issue.

Do you have any idea, how I could implement custom un/-marshalling into the following:

```
@XmlType
public class DataContainer {
  javax.activation.DataSource content;

  // getters/setters
}
```

I would use a XmlAdapter, but a valueType of `byte[]` would not really help with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [data handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html) with JAXB via [@XmlAttachmentRef](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttachmentRef.html)s. Here's a relevant question:

> [How to marshal a DataHandler annotated as @XmlAttachmentRef with JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667869/how-to-marshal-a-datahandler-annotated-as-xmlattachmentref-with-jaxb)

Links:

- https://metro.java.net/guide/ch06.html
- http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html